# How to resolve jekyll sass-converter error while Installation in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jekyll

I want to install jekyll, for that purpose i have installed ruby (ruby version 2.3.3) but the error I am facing the error given above:

**jekyll sass-converter requires ruby version 2.4**

Download Ruby from Links: https://rubyinstaller.org/

I have tried solving the problem by downloading other versions (i.e., 2.4 and 2.5) as well but got the same error. How should I tackle this please guide me in this regard?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby and Ruby-on-Rails are two separate projects.
Ruby is a programming language and Rails is a web framework based on Ruby.

RailsInstaller is an outdated project. Ruby 2.3 has reached end-of-life and the latest rails version is `v6.0.0`.

If you're installing Ruby just to use Jekyll, then you should perhaps look into installing via RubyInstaller instead.

More details in the following link to Jekyll documentation:
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/

---

*P.S. If you are not working on any other Ruby projects, uninstalling existing outdated versions of Ruby will ensure a smoother installation of the more recent versions.*